# How to prove there's a vector $z \in \mathbb{R}^4$ orthogonal to two linearly independent vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^4$ with $\{x, y\}$ being linearly independent. Prove that there exists a non-zero vector $z$ that is orthogonal to both $x$ and $y$.

Any hints on what to do after the obvious step that the only solution to $$c_1x + c_2y = 0$$ is the trivial solution?

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathbf{x}=(a,b,c,d)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(e,f,g,h)$ and $\mathbf{z}=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$.  We simultaneously want $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{z}=0$ and $\mathbf{y} \cdot \mathbf{z}=0$, so any non-trivial solution to the following system of linear equations will do:
\begin{align*}
az_1+bz_2+cz_3+dz_4 &= 0 \\
ez_1+fz_2+gz_3+hz_4 &= 0.
\end{align*}
Equivalently, $\mathbf{z}$ can be any non-zero vector in the [null space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28linear_algebra%29) of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d \\
e & f & g & h \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The [Rank Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) implies that this matrix has non-zero nullity, i.e., the null space has a non-zero vector we can choose for $\mathbf{z}$.  (In fact, the rank will be $2$, since $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are linearly independent.)

Answer (score 4):

The assumption that $x,y$ be linearly independent is not really needed.
Since $\dim \mathbb R^4>2$, there exists a vector $w\notin\operatorname{Span}(x,y)$. Let $z=w+\alpha x+\beta y$ and show that the equations in $\alpha,\beta$ that we obtain from $z\cdot x=0$ and $z\cdot y=0$ have a solution.

Comment: Maybe it's needed since we haven't learned much of what you stated? Is there a solution that uses the assumption?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Pick any vector $w \not\in \langle x , y \rangle$ and apply the [Gram-Schmidt Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to the (ordered) triple $(x, y, w)$.

Answer (score 1):

By construction, consider $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&y_1&*&*\\x_2&y_2&*&*\\x_3&y_3&*&*\\x_4&y_4&*&*\\\end{bmatrix}$$ You can choose the *'s in the third column in a way to guarantee that the first three columns are independent.

- Either $[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ and $[y_1,y_2,y_3]$ are independent in $\mathbb{R}^3$, in which case, use the cross product: $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&y_1&\begin{vmatrix}x_2&y_2\\x_3&y_3\end{vmatrix}&*\\x_2&y_2&-\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1\\x_3&y_3\end{vmatrix}&*\\x_3&y_3&\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1\\x_2&y_2\end{vmatrix}&*\\x_4&y_4&\cdot&*\\\end{bmatrix}$$ and take $\cdot=1$, and its guaranteed that these three columns are independent.
- Or $[x_1,x_2,x_3]=c[y_1,y_2,y_3]$ with at least one of $y_2,y_3$ nonzero, in which case $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&y_1&y_1+1&*\\x_2&y_2&y_2&*\\x_3&y_3&y_3&*\\x_4&y_4&y_4&*\\\end{bmatrix}$$ is guaranteed to have the first three columns independent.
- Or $[x_1,x_2,x_3]=c[y_1,y_2,y_3]$ with $y_2=y_3=0$ nonzero, in which case $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&y_1&0&*\\0&0&1&*\\0&0&0&*\\x_4&y_4&0&*\\\end{bmatrix}$$ is guaranteed to have the first three columns independent.

Now name these new entries: $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1&*\\x_2&y_2&z_2&*\\x_3&y_3&z_3&*\\x_4&y_4&z_4&*\\\end{bmatrix}$$

and use the higher dimensional cross product to get a fourth column (with at least one nonzero entry, since the first thee columns were independent) that is orthogonal to all three first columns (including of course the first two).

$$\begin{bmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}x_2&y_2&z_2\\x_3&y_3&z_3\\x_4&y_4&z_4\end{vmatrix}\\\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1\\x_3&y_3&z_3\\x_4&y_4&z_4\end{vmatrix}\\-\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2&y_2&z_2\\x_4&y_4&z_4\end{vmatrix}\\\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2&y_2&z_2\\x_3&y_3&z_3\end{vmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

A nontrivial example of such a vector $w$ can be constructed as below:

Let $x=[x_1\  x_2\  x_3\  x_4],\ y=[y_1\  y_2\  y_3\  y_4]$. Then, construct $w$ as $w=[w_1\ w_2\ w_3\ 0]$ where $[w_1\ w_2\ w_3]=[x_1\ x_2\ x_3]\times [y_1\ y_2\ y_3]$ where $\times$ denotes the vector cross product. You can easily check that $w$ is orthogonal to both $x,y$. Note that since $x,y$ are linearly independent, $x\times y$ cannot be $0$. That implies that $w$ is non-zero.

Comment: There's some annoying cases here: what if $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ or $[x_1\ x_2\ x_3]=[y_1\ y_2\ y_3]$?

Comment: In both of these cases $w=0$ right?

Comment: and $w=0$ doesn't satisfy the nonzero requirement

Comment: Oh, I see, here the linear independence will play a role. Thanks for pointing out.